# Backticks in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to use the following code as a file `test2.js` with `node.js` version 12.0.

```
let apiKey = '117fa18eaf7312fa52f593c6d52fc48d';
let id = '6094817';
let xu1 = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5.weather?id=$(id)&APPID=$(apiKey)`;
console.log('xul is: ', xul);
```

I get the following results and I am unable to understand why.

```
jgossage@jgossage-XPS-8700:/LinuxData/Projects/node-weather$ node test2.js
/LinuxData/Projects/node-weather/test2.js:4
console.log('value is: ', xul);
                          ^

ReferenceError: xul is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/LinuxData/Projects/node-weather/test2.js:4:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

The only thing I can see is that possibly the template string is not being handled properly, resulting in the variable `xul` being not defined.

Comment: Typo: `xul !== xu1`

Comment: After fixing the typo you will also have to fix the template string.

Comment: Specifically, "...$(id)..." --> "...${id}..." in the template string

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for picking up my typo. I am completely new to Javascript and I cannot see what is wrong with the template string.

Comment: Then you should head over to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) and have a look at: [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @Andreas I have been there and it did not help me. This code comes from a tutorial on using Javascript with node.js so I did not write the template expression.

Comment: @Jonathan then that tutorial is wrong - you shouldn't be using round brackets `()` in the template literal but curly brackets `{}` if you want to use an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andreas mentioned you have a typo it should be 
`console.log('value is: ', xu1);`

but also even if you run that you get
`xu1 is:  http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5.weather?id=$(id)&APPID=$(apiKey)`

That is because you have to use ${} instead of $().
So the final fix is

```
let xu1 = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5.weather?id=${id}&APPID=${apiKey}`;
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with fonts on web pages being too small.